# getting duration of mp3 without javascript library or nodejs

Tags: javascript, mp3

I have an audio element in my html to which im feeding an mp3 file for every item in an array, that works fine. What i want to happen is that it loads its metadata and reads its duration, then continues on to the next item in the array. I tried using `getDuartion.onloadedmetadata' but then that only got the duration of the last mp3 file in the array. With the code below, it logs the correct audio tag, but the duration returns as NaN. Not sure what to do to make this work.

```
getDuration = document.querySelector('.preload-audio')
getDuration.src = `static/mp3/${artistName} - ${songName}.mp3`

console.log(getDuration)
console.log(getDuration.duration)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for it to be loaded. The duration is available as soon as the browser has loaded the meta-data from the file.

You can achieve this with the [onloadeddata Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event).

```js
console.log("direct: audioexample.duration =",audioexample.duration);
audioexample.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(event) {
  if(event.target.readyState >= 2) {
    console.log("waiting: audioexample.duration =",event.target.duration);
  }
});
```

```html
<audio id="audioexample" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" controls></audio>
```

If you want to load the data for multiple files, you have to change the src, after you have the data.

This can be done using promises.

```js
(async () => {
  const audio = document.createElement('audio');
  const list = [
    'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3',
    'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3',
    'some/404/mp3'
  ];
  audio.preload = "metadata";
  for (const item of list) {
      audio.src = item;
      let time = Date.now();
      // wait for it, but max 10 secs, this should skip 404 errors
      while (isNaN(audio.duration) && Date.now() - time < 10000) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,50));
      }
      console.log(audio.src, audio.duration);
  }
})()
```

Another way would be, creating a listener for all existing audio elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("audio").forEach(audio => {
  audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', ({ target }) => {
    if (target.readyState >= 2) {
      console.log(target.src, target.duration);
    }
  });
  audio.addEventListener("error", ({ target, error }) => {
    console.error(target.src, error);
  });
})
```

```html
<audio src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" preload="metadata" controls></audio>
<audio src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3" preload="metadata" controls></audio>
```